# Understanding the proof that $D_4$ is not a direct product of two of its proper subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand how this task works. I've seen multiple proofs online but they all make assumptions which i dont understand.

Proof is:
If $G=H \times K$ with $|H|≥|K|>1$, then every element of H commutes with every element of K ***(WHY?)*** . To claim that G is abelian, we must have both H and K abelian ***(WHY DOES H AND K BEING ABELIAN IMPLY $H \times K$ IS ABELIAN?)***. Notice that $D_4$ has order 8.
The only possible orders for H
and K are $|H|=4$ and $|K|=2$. But this implies that both subgroups are abelian, which in turn makes $G=H \times K$ a commutative group. Thus, we cannot have $G \cong D_4$ because the latter is not abelian.

Again, questions are:

1.Why are the subgroups H and K commutative?

2.Why does H and K being abelian imply their product is abelian?

I'm really having troubles with this and literature isn't helping. Our notes from uni are literally just the definition of direct products.

Proof is from [Proving that $D_4$ can't be expressed as an internal direct product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928534/proving-that-d-4-cant-be-expressed-as-an-internal-direct-product?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) recall that all groups of order $2$ and $4$ are abelian.

For (2) this follows from the definition. Take $(h_1, k_1)$ and $(h_2, k_2)$ in $H \times K$. Then
\begin{align*}
(h_1, k_1) \cdot (h_2, k_2) &= (h_1h_2, k_1k_2)  \\
&= (h_2h_1, k_2k_1) \\
&= (h_2, k_2) \cdot (h_1, k_1)
\end{align*}
where the second equality is commutivity in $H$ and $K$. Hence elements of $H \times K$ commute.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so simple but i just cant seem to develop an intuition for abstract algebra.

Comment: @Hristmar this is exactly the right approach. Thinking critically about proofs in lectures and doing examples is the best way to improve, good luck.